# fstream error cannot create or open file in c++

Tags: c++, fstream

Whenever is ty to enter the option 1 to create a file to store my data
the error gets generated. I am not able to create the file and unable to read it

```
*//cannot create the file*
#include <fstream> 
class file
{   
private:                       
    char data[100];
public:
    void Write();
    void Read();
};
*//this is the write function*     help me
void file::Write() {
    *//fin object is created*
    fstream fin;
    *//cant open the file*
    fin.open("rahul.txt", ios::in);
    if (fin.is_open()) {                             help me
        cout << "Enter data" << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        cin.getline(data, 100);
        fin.close();
    } else
        cout << "error" << endl;          help me
}
*//this is the read function*

void file::Read() {
    *//fout object is created*
    fstream fout;
    *//cant read the file*                   help me
    fout.open("rahul.txt", ios::out);
    if (fout.is_open()) {
        while (!fout.eof()) {
            fout.getline(data, 100);
            cout << data;                     help me
        }
        fout.close();
    } else
        cout << "error" << endl;
}

int main() {
    int choice;
    file f;
    while (1) {
        cout << "Menu" << endl;
        *//cant enter the file when pressed choice 1*
        cout << "1.Enter  2.Display   3.exit" << endl;
        cout << "Enter your choice" << endl;
        cin>>choice;
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                f.Write();
                break;
            case 2:
                f.Read();
                break;                   help me
            case 3:
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
*`//cant enter the file`*
```

Please someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: what exactly is the error? Is it a compiler error? What are all these "help me" ?

Comment: ..btw it is a miracle to me why you consider a page full of volunteers that spend their time to help others as "egoistic"

Comment: I think you mixed up `ios::out` and `ios::in`, for writing you need `ios::out` and for reading `ios::in`!? Also you never output any data to the file.

Comment: Why didn't you provide the error message?

Answer (score 1):

The open mode used in `fin.open("rahul.txt", ios::in);` requires that the file already exists. And is placed in the "current directory", whatever that is, as you don't specify a path.

Mode `in` also only allows you to read from the file.

The open mode used in `fout.open("rahul.txt", ios::out);` will create an empty file for writing (replacing any previous file with the same name). Trying to read from that file will fail for *two* reasons - the file is always empty, and it is open for writing only.